# How to define DNS server in openvpn?

Tags: dns, openvpn

I setup an openvpn server with static key (certificate mode is not usable due to DPI at the national gateway), but I cannot successfully change the DNS automatically after the connection. I searched over the Internet and SE, and every one suggests the use `dhcp-option`.

I tried to add this line to `client.ovpn`

```
dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8
```

There is no effect. I tried to add this line in server conf

```
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
```

Neither has any effect.

In fact, according to the manual,

> --dhcp-option type [parm]
>
> Set extended TAP-Win32 TCP/IP properties, must be used with --ip-win32
>   dynamic or --ip-win32 adaptive.

But my client is a Mac machine, server Linux. Any solutions to the problem?

Comment: You should mention what client you're using on the OSX machine.

Comment: @FloHimself: The standard command line utility `openvpn`.

Answer (score 10):

On a Linux system, you **need to run an external script**.

Here is the documentation:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/OpenVPN#DNS

Scripts are found on [here](https://github.com/masterkorp/openvpn-update-resolv-conf) or newer Linux version [here](https://github.com/jonathanio/update-systemd-resolved) and you can call them by adding this on the openvpn client configuration:

```
script-security 2
up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
```

Comment: If your Linux flavor uses NetworkManager, see [the alterations to work with `nmcli`](https://serverfault.com/a/944262/50236).

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in Ubuntu 16.04.  Is it only functional for some operating systems?

Answer (score 6):

I'm no expert, but from reading the `man` page below your quote:

> --dhcp-option type [parm]
>
> ...
>
> Note that if **--dhcp-option is pushed via --push to a non-windows
>   client**, the option will be saved in the client's environment before
>   the up script is called, under the
>                 name "foreign_option_{n}".

and under *foreign_option_{n}*:

> foreign_option_{n}
>
> An option pushed via --push to a client which does
>   not natively support it, such as **--dhcp-option on a non-Windows
>   system**, will be recorded to this environmental variable sequence prior
>   **to --up script execution**.

So the command line `openvpn` client doesn't automatically modify the DNS setup on your OSX machine after establishing the connection. But since the DNS options are saved to the client's environment, you can specify a script to append the pushed servers to the system's current DNS config with the `--up` option:

> --up cmd
>
> Run command cmd after successful TUN/TAP device open (pre --user UID change).
>
> cmd consists of a path to script (or executable program), optionally followed by arguments. The path and arguments may be
>   single- or double-quoted and/or escaped using
>   a backslash, and should be separated by one or more spaces.

E.g. [Tunnelblick](https://github.com/Tunnelblick/Tunnelblick) also does this by utilizing this [script](https://github.com/Tunnelblick/Tunnelblick/blob/master/tunnelblick/client.up.tunnelblick.sh).

Another solution might be a script that was posted to the openvpn mailing list at [DNS for OS X clients - the Definitive Guide](http://openvpn.net/archive/openvpn-users/2006-10/msg00120.html).

Comment: What about iPhone? Without jailbreaking, I imagine there is no bash or any command to change the DNS automatically.

Comment: @SiyuanRen Without jailbraking you probably don't use the command line openvpn client on an iPhone...

Comment: The official openvpn app simply loads a text configuration file and runs it. There is no more functionality.

Comment: @SiyuanRen Well, the official openvpn app is not the command line application that is discussed here.

Comment: This feels like an hack. When I connect with PPTP or L2TP, there is a dedicated interface available in the Network preferences, with their only IP and DNS. OpenVPN requires me to change the DNS settings of *other* interfaces?

Comment: I'm no expert and mostly just quoting from man page. You may want to start a bounty to get this question more attention.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with both Linux OS (server and client), and I solved itm installing dnsmasq on server that was missing

so my steps:

`apt-get install dnsmasq`

in server.conf

`push "redirect-gateway def1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"`

And I could connect and browse domains through the server IP , connecting with NetWorkManager with DNS sets to automatic

Answer (score -2):

Add this command to your client side conf file..

```
# put actual dns name here
dhcp-option DNS 10.11.12.13
```

It will definitely work..